# TP Link router forwarding

Tags: dns, portforwarding

I am running a webserver on my local network, I am able to connect it via other devices ( like a smartphone ) to that local server, but when I am want to expose it via router forwarding it does not work?

Router config:
[image]

Server / app example:
[image]

Private IP address:
[image]